# What should one do about misspelled tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is a new tag, "etthics". It is a misspelling of "ethics".

I suggested that "etthics" be a synonym for "ethics", but, now that I think about it, that is not what I would like to see happen because it clutters the list of tags with misspelled tags. I think it should just be edited in some way.

Another tag like this is "conciousness". It is a misspelling of the already existing tag "consciousness".

What should one do about misspelled tags?

Answer (score 6):

Simply edit the questions to link to the right tags. Once the misspelled tags have no questions that link to them, they will be automatically removed (see [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags)).

Comment: Good idea. I hadn't thought of that. I hope a couple users will vote-down my synonym suggestion to make sure it doesn't appear.

Comment: Alternately if it really happens often make the bad spelling an alias and then it will auto-switch.